# How much are OT100 tubes worth and what was their specific purpose?

Tags: vacuum-tube

I got this tubes OT100 and I want to know their value, and what are they used for. They are NOS, unused and in working state.

[image: OT 100 tubes]

Comment: As a matter of interest, how much are you selling them for? Strangely, eBay also uses the term "NOS" for their page selling OT100 tubes.

Comment: NOS = new old stock

Comment: @Andyaka That's very common in tubes and other vintage electronics; it stands for "New, Old Stock" and refers to things that were manufactured decades ago, but which are still technically *new* in that they've never been used. Usually they come in the original packaging and everything.

Comment: I think you are missing my point.

Comment: I found them in an old factory in a cardboard with their sleeves and boxes still on, so I am pretty sure they are unused, given the fact that I found in each box a certificate of guaranty dated 1974. I received an offer for 70$ each in Romania, as I saw they are selling for at least 100$ each on Ebay. They are used in large amplifiers like MCintoshMI200 so they are pretty valuable. I have other more and I like to find someone to build an amplifier for me and to give him the rest of them

Answer (score 8):

With a quick search, I was able to find [a reference](https://www.radiomuseum.org/tubes/tube_ot100.html) by searching just "OT100 tube". In the interest of not making this a link-only answer, here's the information I've found:

The logo on them is the Tungsram brand, which was a Hungarian company making vacuum tubes and lightbulbs that apparently only went out of business last year (2022).

They're triodes, with an unusual four-pin base and a top contact for the anode, indicating that they're probably high-voltage/high-power tubes. The site I linked above claims that they're radio transmitter tubes, which would make sense given the top contact; transmitters are often fairly high power.

The filament is a 10 V, 32 W(!) directly-heated cathode between pins 1 and 4, the grid is pin 3, and the anode is the cap on top. Pin 2 is not connected. I'm afraid I can't tell you how to identify pin 1 (unless it's labelled with a clear molded "1", as these sometimes were), because I've never seen that particular base before. Several sources claim that the OT100 is equivalent to the 8005, which was produced by a number of American companies including RCA.

[image]
<sup><sub>([image source](https://www.radiomuseum.org/tubes/tube_8005.html); page is about the 8005, which has the same pinout as the OT100. Their image for the OT100 is hard to read.)</sub></sup>

I wasn't able to find one for the OT100 itself, but here's a [datasheet](https://frank.pocnet.net/sheets/049/8/8005.pdf) for the equivalent 8005. When reading the datasheet, be aware that μμF is the old-fashioned term for what we call a pF today; the datasheet predates the modern SI prefixes.

Comment: Much to my surprise, indeed it's only in 1958/1960 that prefixes for units, like pF, where adopted (resolution 3 adopted by the International Committee of Weights and Measures, 1958; and 11th General Conference on Weights and Measures, 1960).

Comment: @fgrieu-onstrike And after that it took a few years for the conventions to take hold. Learning electronics in the 60's, I was used to seeing pF written as µµF or MMF, along with other oddities (kMc for GHz, ...).

Comment: @JohnDoty I'm surprised it wasn't kMcps; the 1930s book about vacuum tubes that I have uses cps (cycles per second, if that's not obvious), I suppose it must have gotten abbreviated by the 60s.

Comment: Stromberg-Carlson's engineering data for its 1935 58-T multiband receiver uses kc for radio frequencies, "cycles" for mains. It also uses ω for ohms, and Ω for megohms. The Radiotron Designer's handbook, (Langford-Smith, 1952) uses Mc/s and Kc/s (!). The RCA Receiving Tube Handbook (RC-19, 1959) uses Mc. The language and notation weren't stable until the late 60's. I remember being confused by the statement that clock ticks from the time signal station WWV were "5 cycles of a 1000 cycle tone".

Comment: Note that the symbols for pins 1 and 4 are larger than pins 2 and 3. The physical pins on the actual tube follow a similar pattern -- pins 1 and 4 are larger diameter.

Comment: That's right. Also, you can indentifly them by the 5th pin placed on the ceramic socket, as seen in the botton tube from the picture.